# How to determine ip address for CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, nuget, aws-codebuild

I have a private nuget that's locked down. Only whitelisted ip addresses may connect to it. My aws CodeBuild project needs to make a connection to restore some nugets.

May I ask how do I determine what port and ip address I should be whitelisting so my CodeBuild can communicate with my private nuget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to [run your CodeBuild process in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/vpc-support.html). One of the use cases listed in that documentation is:

> Query external web services that require fixed IP addresses through the Elastic IP address of the NAT gateway or NAT instance associated with your subnet.

The VPC would need to be configured with a NAT Gateway with an Elastic IP attached to it, and CodeBuild would need to be configured to run in a private subnet of the VPC with a route to the NAT Gateway.